# Passing object pointer as first argument for a member function: is it standard?

Tags: c++, c++11

The following program compiles with both gcc and clang, but is this actually standard C++11 or do both compilers choose to support it for convenience?

```
struct Foo {
    int i;

    void bar() { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    std::function<void(Foo*)> method = &Foo::bar;

    Foo myFoo{4};
    method(&myFoo); // prints 4
}
```

This is certainly convenient, but I don't understand how/why it works.

Comment: It works as with any class member function pointer, that requires _`this`_ for calling (just hides the ugly stuff). What do you not understand in particular? As is your question looks a bit too broad.

Comment: Yes, that's standard. G++ supports this here in addition though: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Bound-member-functions.html

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think he's curious that this seems to be a place where the standard exposes the implementation detail that `this` is an argument to member functions.

Comment: Yeah, what @OliverCharlesworth said.

Comment: Related: [How do i write a pointer-to-member-function with std::function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9281172/335858). There is a good explanation of how this "magic" works in one of the answers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I think, that OP does not understand why void (__thiscall Foo::*)(void) converts to void (__cdecl*)(struct Foo *)

Comment: @user2451677 That one is easy: it doesn't. :)

Comment: @hvd: Yes, those calling-conventions are incompatible. GCC allows it as an extension when the calling-conventions are compatible though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that is standard. [func.wrap.func.inv] specifies that the `operator()(ArgTypes&&... args)` 
of `std::function` calls

> *INVOKE* `(f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., R)` (20.8.2), where `f` is the target object (20.8.1) of `*this`.

<sub>(Where `R` is the specified return type.)</sub>

[func.require] defines *`INVOKE`*:

> Define *`INVOKE`* `(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> - `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an
>     object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from
>     `T`;
> - `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in
>     the previous item;
> - […]

Note that the trailing `R` in the call is used for the conversion to `R` (the return type of the `function`):

> Define *`INVOKE`* `(f, t1, t2, ..., tN, R)` as *`INVOKE`* `(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` implicitly converted to `R`.

The first and only argument you give is the pointer to the `Foo`-object. The call to `method`  thus results in the call `(void)((*t1).*f)()` which is, when written with your given values, equivalent to
 `((*(&myFoo)).&Foo::bar)()`, which is equivalent to `myFoo.bar()`.

Comment: A shame they didn't just define a function `std::invoke` while they were at it...

Comment: @Deduplicator Well, it's more or less trivially implemented - one has to consider the ranking via a priority-based overload resolution mechanism though,  there was a bugged implementation in libstdc++ IIRC.

Comment: What the what! You can make a function point to member data too? (`std::function<int&(Foo&)> data = &Foo::i;`) Man I'm learning all sorts of things today.

Comment: @Barry Yes, covered in the same quotes.

Comment: @Deduplicator A few years late better than never?