# How to typedef the return type of a method from a template class?

Tags: c++, types, c++14, return-type-deduction

I have a templated class `Helper` which looks like this:

```
template< typename Mapper >
class Helper
{
public:

   using mappedType = ... ;

};
```

I would need `mappedType` to be the type returned by the `map(const int&)` method in the `Mapper` class. Given a valid type for `Mapper` like the following:

```
class DMapper
{
public:

    double map(const int& val){ ... }
};
```

`Helper<DMapper>::mappedType` should be `double`. Is there a way to do that without instantiating a `Mapper`?

The closest I got is:

```
using mappedType = typename std::result_of<
    decltype(&Mapper::map)(Mapper const*, const int&)
>::type;
```

But `type` is not defined in this case.

**EDIT:**

If I can avoid using a dummy argument for the `int`, that would be even better (in my concrete code, the argument is not that simple).

Comment: Do you actually need the name in `Dmapper`?  Since you have C++14 you can just use `auto` like `auto function(stuff) { return whatever; }`

Comment: Yep, I know that there are other way to achieve my goal (I need to return a `std::vector` of `mappedType` in a method from the `Helper`), that was more out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The closest I got is
>
> `using mappedType = typename std::result_of<decltype(&Mapper::map)(Mapper const*, const int&)>::type;`

You almost got it.

Auto-declared `this` pointer is not constant in non-constant class methods, so your

```
decltype(&Mapper::map)(Mapper const*, const int&)
```

does not match any method in `Mapper` class. Remove `const` qualifier from the first argument, and your `result_of` solution will work without instancing and dummy arguments:

```
using mappedType = typename std::result_of<
    decltype(&Mapper::map)(Mapper /*no const here*/ *, const int&)
>::type;
```

Comment: I did not think that I was that close to a solution... Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: I accept this one since it was very close to what I got, event if the answer from wasthishelpful works equally well.

Comment: Is the "auto-declared" `this` pointer described in the standard or platform-specific? I must say this is the first time I've seen it explicitly written like that (even though 'everybody knows' it's just another argument).

Comment: @TheVee Yes, it is standard. It's presence in all member functions is described by sections 9.3.1-9.3.2 of the Standard. And it's declaration as the first argument of any non-static method is required, for example, in section 2.9.12 [func.require]. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692378/passing-object-pointer-as-first-argument-for-a-member-function-is-it-standard

Comment: This breaks if `map` is overloaded, unlike the `declval` solution.

Answer (score 33):

You can use [`std::declval`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to use member functions in `decltype` without creating an instance:

```
using mappedType = decltype(std::declval<Mapper>().map(0));
```

`std::declval` can be used for arguments as well:

```
using mappedType = decltype(std::declval<Mapper>().map(std::declval<int>()));
```

Comment: Mhhh nice! Can you do the same without having to specify some kind of dummy argument for the method (here 0 for the int), because it's not that simple in reality

Comment: Very slick use of `declval`. :)

Comment: @Dr_Sam why are you concerned about the dummy argument, is it because its a reference to a more complicated type? Remember that you can always also use `declval` for the dummy argument itself.

Comment: @Smeeheey Indeed, `using mappedType = decltype(std::declval<Mapper>().map(std::declval<const int&>()));` works fine

Comment: @Dr_Sam: The main advantage of the dummy argument (or a use of `declval` again) is that unlike your attempted solution conversion rules and overload resolution apply. So for example if I was to create a mapper with a `double map(long)` it would still work, likewise if `map` had a second (defaulted) argument, or was template, or...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `Mapper::map` is not an overloaded method, its return type can be resolved automatically as follows:

```
template< typename Mapper >
class Helper
{
private:
    template<class R, class... T>
    static R resolveReturnType(R (Mapper::*)(T...));

    template<class R, class... T>
    static R resolveReturnType(R (Mapper::*)(T...) const);

public:
    using mappedType = decltype(resolveReturnType(&Mapper::map));
};
```